# Trying to speed up list compare in EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which compares two lists in the same worksheet and deletes the entire row from one of the two lists, however it is now running very slowly (as the data grows) and I am trying to speed up the process.

I am not succeeding in doing this to any great extent and I'm looking for some assistance,

Thanks!

The code:

```
Sub Clean_Up_Lists()
'run comparisons... clean up lists'

'turn of screen updating to speed up macro'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim iListCount As Long
Dim x As Range
Dim iCtr As Long


'get count of records to search through(list that will be deleted)'
iListCount = Sheets("Allocations").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row


For Each x In Sheets("Allocations").Range("N200:N400" & Sheets("Allocations").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)



'loop through all records in the second list'
For iCtr = iListCount To 1 Step -1

If x.Value = Sheets("Allocations").Cells(iCtr, 2).Value Then
Sheets("Allocations").Cells(iCtr, 2).EntireRow.ClearContents
'if match exists --> clear contents from allocations list'

End If
Next iCtr
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: what you expect this part `"N200:N400" & Sheets("Allocations").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` should do?

Comment: It's about 12 months since this code was implemented, my recollection is that it was to define the list of values which compare for the deletion. (essentially looping through the master list)

Re-reading it now, I wonder if there is redundancy in doing this?

Comment: if the last used tow, say, 500, this line `"N200:N400" & Sheets("Allocations").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` gives you `"N200:N400500"`. Not sure it's what you need

Comment: All it really needs to compare is N200:N400

Comment: so, it needs to compare each cell in column B with cells in `N200:N400` and if cell in column B found in range `N200:N400` - then clear contents?

Comment: Yes, if duplicate present, then clear contents of the row in column B where the duplicate exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub Clean_Up_Lists()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim rngToClear As Range
    Dim arr

    With Sheets("Allocations")
        Set rng = .Range("N200:N400")
        arr = .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(arr(i, 1), rng, 0)) Then
                If rngToClear Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToClear = .Range("B" & i)
                Else
                    Set rngToClear = Union(rngToClear, .Range("B" & i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not rngToClear Is Nothing Then rngToClear.EntireRow.ClearContents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks simoco.
It worked well on my mac at home, on the test file I run. Much appreciated.

Will test it out on the work PC I have to run it on for real tomorrow.